# App not showing as installed on debug React Native 0.56

Tags: android, react-native

I have a weird situation occurring right now.

Two cases

1. Emulator running - `react-native run-android` gets installed as an application on the emulator in debug mode and is visible in the application list screen.
2. Real device running - `react-native run-android` gets installed on the device, but I can't see the installed application on the application list screen. So, to open the app again, I need to run the command `react-native run-android` again. When I disconnect the device, an alert pops up, giving a message similar to `Application XYZ process stopped` (I don't remember the exact message)

Is there any additional settings that need to be done in order to see it as installed?

Use case - I have a deep link arriving on an sms. Need to open an app for the same, but it opens the same in the web browser (I have my deep link scheme in the manifest file).

My current conclusion - Since, the app is not visible as installed, maybe that's why the intent is not getting recognized as a deep link.

```
    <application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <data
            android:host="xyz.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/"
            android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

Any thoughts?
Note - Using RN 0.56.

Comment: can you show me you AndroidManifest file? what does your  `intent-filter` below your `main activity` looks like

Comment: done, please have a look

Comment: yep，i think you should create a new intent-filter and put  your `deep link` config into it.